# Error when starting Liferay 7 (liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1): PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, liferay

I am getting the following error when starting Liferay (liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1):

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in
>   invoking javac.   A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

I have set my **system environment variables** correctly:

- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
- JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

I have added my JAVA_HOME path to my system Path variable:

- ....;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;

When I run the windows **where javac** command, I get the following:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javac.exe

What am I missing??  I have also tried using JDK 1.8 and JDK 1.7.0_79. Same results.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you just give a try by removing JRE_HOME system environment variable and then try..

Answer (score 11):

After a lot of trial and error, and a lot of searching and several Windows Environment Setting Changes, I resolved this issue. I will point to the last 2 locations that led me to get over the finish-line because I had done some many things.

**1)** I made sure my JAVA_HOME pointed to my Java JDK (1.8.0_xx) and my JRE_HOME pointed to my Java JRE (1.8.0_xx)

**2)** I removed the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; from my PATH variables (there were 2 PATH variables, removed from both)

**3)** Made sure my PATH variables (both) at the JDK Bin folder path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;

Then I checked my CMD 'where java' and received the correct response:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe

**4)** In Eclipse, under the top menu: Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
Here, I originally had the jre1.8.0_65, but I added the jdk1.8.0_65 and selected it.

**5) Finally**, what seemed to make the biggest difference:
Right-Click on your server, and at the bottom, select Properties.
A window will open up, and the 3rd option, there's clickable text "Runtime Environment". Click it and a popup will open, there will be a bottom drop-down under "Select runtime JRE" Here, I selected **jdk1.8.0_65**

That finally corrected the issue for me. Here are 2 links in reverse order.

http://www.huqiwen.com/2016/05/11/liferay-7-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac/

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74821940?_19_threadView=tree

Comment: I change Installed JREs to JDK folder and it works, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this is complete solution.

Comment: Step 4 mentioned above nailed it for me. Thanks

Comment: Step 4 for me also !

Answer (score 1):

In your environment both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are set. In this case Tomcat  will prefer the JRE_HOME over the JAVA_HOME. JRE_HOME should point to a JRE while JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK. 
You could just delete the JRE_HOME environment variable and Tomcat would automatically switch to JAVA_HOME so the isseue would be solved. If you want to keep the JRE_HOME in Windows you can change the setenv.bat by adding the following line as a first line.

```
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
```

This change will tell Tomcat that the JRE_HOME should be considered equal to JAVA_HOME and will not change your environmental variables.