# JDK missing, but is installed

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-7, eclipse-mars

I have to learn about Liferay 7.x on Eclipse Mars.2 on Windows 10. 
So, I installed the JDK 1.8.0_201 and added in in the Eclipse Preferences.

But still, I have the error :

> "There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is
>   required"

I also already set my environment variables.

```
JAVA_HOME
JRE_HOME
```

How can fix this ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you added the JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME/bin to your path? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer and see if you can find anything that you can do to solve your issue. And if yes, write back what was your problem.

[Error when starting Liferay 7 (liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1): PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.A full JDK (not just JRE) is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170580/error-when-starting-liferay-7-liferay-portal-7-0-ce-ga1-pwc6345-there-is-an)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunatly, it does not work for me. I still get this error. I tried multiple paths for the variable environments (to the bin folders of the JDK and the JRE) with and without the (x86). 

Tho, after deleting the PATH variables  C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath 
the "where java" command does not return results anymore.